# Парсинг информации и её сортировка по убыванию (цифры)

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!
Нужно, чтобы PHP скрипт заходил на страницу `http://site1.ru/`, парсил информацию из тегов

```
<td>10000 $</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">2</td>
```

- 10000 $ - инфа, которую необходимо спарсить.
  А потом, заходил на `http://site2.ru/`, также парсил информацию и сортировал по убыванию.

Comment: Ну и где ваш код, где ваши попытки мысли и т.д.?<br>
Мы не на сайте фриланса...

Comment: Я прошу лишь дать материал по данной теме. Думаю, что надо копать в сторону file_get_contents, но пока безуспешно ищу...

Comment: Ну так какие проблемы то?<br>
У вас в вопросе сразу 2 задачи описаны, вы сначало расспарсите а потом уже думайте о сортировке, для парсинга в вашем случае скорее всего `file_get_contents` подходит на ура...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Материалы по данной теме:

[`curl`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)`/`[`fsockopen`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.fsockopen.php) (для получения инфы)

[`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php) и [`мануал по регуляркам`](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1) (для парсинга)

[`инфа по сортировке массивов`](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl4_4.php)

[`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysql.php) (для сохранения)

Это самая частая связка, а алгоритм чуть ли не из этих функций с параметрами и в правильном порядке собирается. Получили текст - вытащили подходящие значения - рассортировали - записали в базу.

Comment: Как определить самое большое число?

Comment: Примерно так:

    $arr = array(1, 4, 2, 15, 10003, 12);
    $maxn = max($arr);
    echo $maxn; // 10003